# Questions about food supplements

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there anywhere I can ask questions about (human) food supplements (like vitamins, minerals, etc.)?

Comment: You might take a look to [Health beta](http://health.stackexchange.com/) and see if your questions would fit.

Comment: I'll try that, cheers!

Comment: It probably depends on the particular question. There is [cooking.se] (but I think they don't really entertain such questions) and then there's also [fitness.se] and [health.se]. But each site has its own rules and restrictions regarding food questions, so it's not clear if your particular question would be on-topic right away.

Comment: @ChristianRau my question is about a specific multi-vitamin product (specifically, if Solgar "Multi Vitamin Multi Male" is the same things as "Advanced Phytonutrient Male Mutiple" and if not, what's the differences).

Comment: @traveh You might want to add this information into the question then.

Comment: @traveh: From what point-of-view do you expect an answer? The physics side? The health impact?

Comment: For certain types of questions on health claims of food supplements you may also think about Skeptics

Comment: @PatrickHofman assuming that the products are different I want to know the difference in ingredients (I couldn't find it online), but additional information in respect to the difference in the aspect of the health impact would be very welcome.

Comment: Wow so many options... :)

Comment: Honestly?  Because the previous question was spam for health food supplements. http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/256645/revisions (10k)

Comment: @Won't indeed. Supplements aren't really loved here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the help center of Health](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), it might be a site where your question is on-topic.

If you ask about the health effects of some product, this seems to fit:

- ... nutritional factors that affect health;
- Medications and other interventions that are used to treat diseases

Also check out their [micronutrients tag](https://health.stackexchange.com/tags/micronutrients/info).

I would recommend to read their help center carefully, and if you are in doubt maybe ask in one of the chat rooms of that site if it is on-topic. Also, I would try to get the list of ingredients yourself, since that isn't really a good question to ask in my opinion.

Comment: I agree, but I did try to find the list of ingredients myself and I can't find it anywhere online :/

Comment: @traveh: It might not get well-received to ask for the ingredients. Maybe give it a try in chat?

Comment: Sure, will do. I also sent the same questions to Solgar themselves but I don't know if / when I'll get an answer...